# How to append text to option by checking option's value which are not in a json response from a ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp-3.0

This is something I have came upto..
Can somebody tell how to check the values of the option 
and append some text only to them which have values as compared to stored in a json response or an array.

```
function checkDuplicates() {
    var category_id = $('#category-id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: base_url + 'NotificationStageEmployeeMappings/checkDuplicates',
        data: {'category_id': category_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#child-id option').each(function () {
                var value = result.dataJson; //also used var value = ["6","2"];
                if ($.inArray($(this).val(), value) === 1) {
                    $(this).append("<small> *already selected*</small>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: By checking `=== 1`, you're looking only to see if the value is the second thing in the array (0 is the first position). Is that what you meant? Presumably `!== -1` is what you really wanted there?

Comment: Also [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) indicates that "The comparison between values is strict", so be sure that the types of the things you're comparing match, not just the values.

Comment: Yes !== -1 does the trick..